# Lebesgue integration in $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

I'm confused as to how we are supposed to integrate

$$\frac{1}{\pi}\int_U\left[\frac{d}{dz}\left( \frac{z-\alpha}{1-\bar\alpha z }\right)\right]^2 \, dm$$

where $U$ is the unit disc, $|\alpha|<1$, and $m$ denotes Lebesgue measure. I've attempted turning this into a double integral with $r\in(0,1)$ and $\theta\in(0,2\pi)$, but I keep getting stuck. Is there a trick I'm missing in this process? Thanks!

Comment: Can you show what you've tried explicitly and where you get stuck? That could really help us to help you.

Comment: Are you integrating with respect to $z$ or with respect to $\alpha$ or something else? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: We assume $\alpha$ is constant and you're integrating $dxdy$ where $z=x+iy$?